# While Request for location permission, app is crashing in iOS only. in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, geolocation

[image]I am trying to request for location permission.when call goes to requestPermissionAsync, Whole app is crashing, I have Attached my code below please go throw it.

```cs
var hasPermission = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
if (hasPermission == PermissionStatus.Unknown)
{
    var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
    hasPermission = results[Permission.Location];
}
if (hasPermission == PermissionStatus.Denied)
{
    var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
    hasPermission = results[Permission.Location];
    if (hasPermission == PermissionStatus.Denied)
    {
        string zipCode = await cache.GetObject<string>(AppConstants.USER_LOCATION_ZIPCODE_KEY);
        settingsService.AddItem(AppConstants.USER_LOCATION_ZIPCODE_KEY, zipCode);
        settingsService.AddItem(AppConstants.USER_LOCATION_LAT_KEY, "");
        settingsService.AddItem(AppConstants.USER_LOCATION_LON_KEY, "");

    }
    else if (hasPermission == PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position currentPosition = await locator.GetPositionAsync(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10, 0));

        var addressList = await locator.GetAddressesForPositionAsync(currentPosition, null);

        foreach (var item in addressList)
        {
            settingsService.AddItem(AppConstants.USER_LOCATION_ZIPCODE_KEY, item.PostalCode);
            settingsService.AddItem(AppConstants.USER_LOCATION_LAT_KEY, item.Latitude.ToString());
            settingsService.AddItem(AppConstants.USER_LOCATION_LON_KEY, item.Longitude.ToString());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

please help me and Thanks in Advance.

StackTrace:

```xml
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
  at System.Net.Http.NSUrlSessionHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001d4] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.8.3.0/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSUrlSessionHandler.cs:459
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncWorker (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption completionOption, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0009e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:281
  at Qualbe1DMobileApp.Repository.GenericRepository+<>c__DisplayClass3_1`2[T,TR].<PostAsync>b__2 () [0x0003f] in /Users/admin/Desktop/1DentalMobile/1DM_Development/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Repository/GenericRepository.cs:147
  at Polly.Policy+<>c__DisplayClass181_0`1[TResult].<ExecuteAsyncInternal>b__0 (Polly.Context ctx, System.Threading.CancellationToken ct) [0x0003d] in C:\projects\polly\src\Polly.Shared\Policy.Async.cs:63
  at Polly.RetrySyntaxAsync+<>c__DisplayClass25_1.<WaitAndRetryAsync>b__1 (Polly.Context ctx, System.Threading.CancellationToken ct) [0x0003d] in C:\projects\polly\src\Polly.Shared\Retry\RetrySyntaxAsync.cs:545
  at Polly.Retry.RetryEngine.ImplementationAsync[TResult] (System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] action, Polly.Context context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] shouldRetryExceptionPredicates, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] shouldRetryResultPredicates, System.Func`1[TResult] policyStateFactory, System.Boolean continueOnCapturedContext) [0x00077] in C:\projects\polly\src\Polly.Shared\Retry\RetryEngineAsync.cs:29
  at Polly.Retry.RetryEngine.ImplementationAsync[TResult] (System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] action, Polly.Context context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] shouldRetryExceptionPredicates, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] shouldRetryResultPredicates, System.Func`1[TResult] policyStateFactory, System.Boolean continueOnCapturedContext) [0x0025d] in C:\projects\polly\src\Polly.Shared\Retry\RetryEngineAsync.cs:50
  at Polly.Policy.ExecuteAsyncInternal[TResult] (System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] action, Polly.Context context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Boolean continueOnCapturedContext) [0x000b2] in C:\projects\polly\src\Polly.Shared\Policy.Async.cs:61
  at Polly.Policy.ExecuteAsync[TResult] (System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] action, Polly.Context context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Boolean continueOnCapturedContext) [0x00073] in C:\projects\polly\src\Polly.Shared\Policy.Async.ExecuteOverloads.cs:261
  at Qualbe1DMobileApp.Repository.GenericRepository.PostAsync[T,TR] (System.String uri, T data, System.String funcKey, System.String authToken, System.String appId, System.String appKey) [0x004a6] in /Users/admin/Desktop/1DentalMobile/1DM_Development/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Repository/GenericRepository.cs:177
  at Qualbe1DMobileApp.Services.Data.MemberService.GetMemberInfo (System.Int64 memberid) [0x00081] in /Users/admin/Desktop/1DentalMobile/1DM_Development/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Services/Data/MemberService.cs:34
  at Qualbe1DMobileApp.ViewModels.AccountLandPageViewModel.ShowOptions () [0x00117] in /Users/admin/Desktop/1DentalMobile/1DM_Development/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Qualbe1DMobileApp/ViewModels/AccountLandPageViewModel.cs:48
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1021
  at Foundation.NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.8.3.0/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSAction.cs:178
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.8.3.0/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.8.3.0/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65
  at Qualbe1DMobileApp.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /Users/admin/Desktop/1DentalMobile/1DM_Development/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Qualbe1DMobileApp.iOS/Main.cs:17
```

Comment: FYI Stacktrace and message would really help us

Comment: @FreakyAli I have attached exception's screen shot

Comment: Screenshots do not actually help. Just like in your case the exception is happening somewhere else and it shows in the Main.cs of iOS. Debug to the exact point it is crashing from, Then add a try-catch and give us the Stacktrace.

Comment: Also, make sure you have Usage description added in the `info.plist` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/security-privacy?tabs=windows

Comment: The Plugin.Geolocator is old one, you can use Xamarin.Essentials Geolocation.
Please check following Microsoft doc [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android)

Comment: Your app's `Info.plist` must contain the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key in order to access the device’s location in iOS. Also, add a try-catch when you request the permission and get the detail of exception.

Comment: This is not related to geolocation, it is not asking for ocation permission

Comment: @FreakyAli I have added stacktrace

Comment: Do you have the permission details added in the info.plist!

Comment: A task was canceled generally means it just finished on timeout, so your task was waiting for something and got nothing, dig this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your Stack Trace your code fails because of a Task you are starting and is cancelled:

```
  at Qualbe1DMobileApp.Repository.GenericRepository.PostAsync[T,TR] (System.String uri, T data, System.String funcKey, System.String authToken, System.String appId, System.String appKey) [0x004a6] in /Users/admin/Desktop/1DentalMobile/1DM_Development/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Repository/GenericRepository.cs:177
  at Qualbe1DMobileApp.Services.Data.MemberService.GetMemberInfo (System.Int64 memberid) [0x00081] in /Users/admin/Desktop/1DentalMobile/1DM_Development/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Services/Data/MemberService.cs:34
  at Qualbe1DMobileApp.ViewModels.AccountLandPageViewModel.ShowOptions () [0x00117] in /Users/admin/Desktop/1DentalMobile/1DM_Development/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Qualbe1DMobileApp/Qualbe1DMobileApp/ViewModels/AccountLandPageViewModel.cs:48
```

So either `MemberService` line 32 or `AccountLandPageViewModel` line 48 should catch and handle this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All, Actually i am calling some API's before asking location permission. so before response from API it comes to location permission that's why app is crashing now work fine.Thanks for you valuable time.